# React Nativeでフォームの値を取得したい

Tags: react-native

React Nativeでフォームのinputに入力された値を取得したいのですが、どう取得するかわかりません。
React Native Elementを使っています。
Reactなら
`<input type="button" onClick={this.someFunc.bind(this)} value="test" />`
と言うように、.bind(this)としてフォーム内容の値を受けわたすと思います。

ReactNativeの場合、Component（クラス）でinputの値を受け取ってsetStateする時、
コンポーネントを使う側はどうしたらいいでしょうか。

```
<FormInput onChangeText={() => this.setState({name: （ここがわからない）})}/>
```

上記で、Reactを使うときと同じく、this.someFunc.bind(this)とするのでしょうか。
普通にthis.nameとしたら値が入っていませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormInput は使ったことがないのでおそらくですが、 onChangeText のイベントには入力の文字列が引数として渡ってきていないでしょうか。

```
<FormInput onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({name: text})}/>
```

上記のようにすると、解決しませんか?